# text scrolling within div element

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have created a multibox helper in mvc3 using div and all the items appear perfectly and vertical scrolling works fine too but when i scroll down slowly within div some text appear blur and if i let it go for few secs it adjusts and the text is visible good. This appears as if i am buffering the data while scrolling.

Any suggestions?

This is the css i am using on div

```
 border: gray 1px solid;
 width: 350px;
 height: 150px;
 float: left;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 background-color: White;
```

Comment: Just for covering all the bases... have you tried it on other monitors? Maybe it's just something weird with that specific one.. just a shot in the dark because I have weird issues with one of mine sometimes

Comment: i tried but i still having that issue.